# How to detect when processing is finished for multiple ajax calls in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming I have the following:

```
function main() {

  var finished = false;

  for(var i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    do(i);
  }
}

function do(i) {
  $.ajax({
   url:"myurl.com/"+i,
   datatype:"text/xml",
   success: function() {

        // Two more layers of multiple nested $.ajax elements here
   }
  })
}
```

Is there some way I could pop an alert box after all the "do" are finished after the three iterations? How? Syntax would help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An ajax call returns a jQuery Promise object. You could collect the output of each one in an array, and use `$.when` to 'bundle' the promises together.

This code is the basic idea behind what you want:

```
function main() {

  var finished = false;

  var defs = [];

  for(var i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    defs.push(do(i));
  }

  $.when.apply(null, defs).done(function() {
    //this code will only run when all ajax calls are complete
  });
}

function do(i) {
  var promise = $.ajax({
   url:"myurl.com/"+i,
   datatype:"text/xml",
   success: function() {

        // Two more layers of multiple nested $.ajax elements here
   }
  })

  return promise;
}
```

The browser can have a lot of open HTTP connections, don't let the naysayers convince you otherwise. Here is a table of maximum concurrent connections supported by browser. Let your site usage statistics be your guide, but even 2 ajax requests at once is faster than totally synchronous data requests...

```
Firefox 2:  2
Firefox 3+: 6
Opera 9.26: 4
Opera 12:   6
Safari 3:   4
Safari 5:   6
IE 7:       2
IE 8:       6
IE 10:      8
Chrome:     6
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just make the calls synchronous?

Comment: Then the they all take longer? That point of ajax is that you can get many calls to happen at once.

Comment: the max you can have open at once is 2... And that is not the *point* of ajax, it just happens to be an `option`.

Comment: Yeah in IE6 and FF2. Everyone else these days is way mo' betta

Comment: There is no single point of ajax. The most important benefit however imho is that you never have to write ugly form tags.

Comment: Well, and you can keep the DOM as long as you want because the browser never reloads...

Answer (score 2):

As global:

```
var complete = 0;
```

All AJAX calls;

```
$.ajax({
  ... //other attributes,
  complete: function(){
    complete++;
    if (complete == 3) {
      alert('all completed');
    }
  }
});
```

This would execute when three AJAX calls are done.  However, if you need to increase it, then do so.

Comment: Deferreds and promises are a much cleaner way to solve this problem, especially when the number of ajax calls might be variable so you can't hardcode in 3

Comment: Globals are not needed for this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of statuses for this:

```
function main() {
  var ready = new Array(3);
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    ready[i] = false;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    do(i, ready);
  }
}

function do(i, ready) {
  $.ajax({
   url:"myurl.com/"+i,
   datatype:"text/xml",
   success: function() {
     // If there are multiple layers then the next statements should be executed in the last layer.
     ready[i] = true;
     if (isAllReady(ready)) {
       alert("All done!");
     }
   }
  })
}

function isAllReady(ready) {
  var allReady = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (!ready[i]) {
      allReady = false;
    }
  }
  return allReady;
}
```